# How to center the div in the flexbox, or how to simplify the center-right layout?

Tags: html, css

This is a common question. But I can not find a glossary to describe it.
It's just a pagination component, the pages in the center of the row, and the total pages in the right of the row.
[image]

To center the pages component, with code:

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;position: relative">
    <div style="flex: 1 1 0%;"></div>
    <div>
        <button>&lt;</button>
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 1 1 0%;"></div>

    <div style="position: absolute; right: 0">
        <span> total pages: 5</span>
        <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

It's working correctly now. But it looks verbosely. I am not familiar with CSS. Hope to get your advice, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more simple without the empty `div`s.
In **css-tricks** there is a really good guie about **[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.items-center{
  align-items: center;
}
.justify-end{
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
        <div class="flex justify-end items-center">
            <button>&lt;</button>
            <button>1</button>
            <button>2</button>
            <button>3</button>
            <button>&gt;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="flex justify-end items-center">
            <span> total pages: 5</span>
            <select style="margin-left:10px">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In this condition, the 1,2,3,4,5 is just the center of the left part. not the whole row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your code is doing:

In the first line by using `display: flex; justify-content: center;`, your div would appear in one line as a flex and aligned center horizontally.
Read more about flex at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

By using `position: relative` div is given a relative position so its child element would change its position according to parent div. You can read about position property more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

`flex: 1 1 0%;` means it can grow or shrink according to width.

By styling `position: absolute; right: 0` it is positioned relative to the parent div and would be on the exactly right of page

By using this description, you can change your code according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of those expanding divs by setting the justify-content to "space-around" which surrounds the content of the div on both sides.

[edit] idk why it doesn't work in the "run code snippet" but I just checked in an html file in Firefox and Chrome, and it does work.

```css
    <style>
      .pagination {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        position: relative;
      }
      .pagination-menu {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
      }
    </style>
```

```html
    <div class="pagination">
      <div>
        <button>&lt;</button>
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>&gt;</button>
      </div>

      <div class="pagination-menu">
        <span> total pages: 5</span>
        <select>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```